# How to get View from google maps Marker?

Tags: android, android-studio, google-maps, google-maps-markers, google-maps-android-api-2

I want to add showcaseview to a marker on android maps!?
the showcase library takes view as argument.
How do i get View from Marker?

I am trying this code

```
new GuideView.Builder(this)
    .setTitle("Guide Title Text")
    .setContentText("Guide Description Text\n .....Guide Description Text\n .....Guide Description Text .....")
    .setGravity(Gravity.auto) //optional
    .setDismissType(DismissType.anywhere) //optional - default DismissType.targetView
    .setTargetView(view)
    .setContentTextSize(12)//optional
    .setTitleTextSize(14)//optional
    .build()
    .show();
```

its takes view as argument in setTargetView, not Marker Object

here is he library i want to use
https://github.com/mreram/ShowCaseView

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Marker` is not view and you can't get `View` from it. But anyway you can create dummy transparent `View` and place it over the selected marker programmatically, then pass it to ShowCaseView library via `setTargetView` method. So, you need root view around your `MapFragment` or `MapView`, e.g `RelativeLayout` (`activity_main.xml`):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/mapview_root"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="<YOUR_PACKAGE_NAME>.MainActivity">

    <com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView android:id="@+id/mapview"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

and dummy transparent view layout (`transparent_layout.xml`):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<View
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="20dp"  <- adjust size programmatically or set to default size of Marker
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent">
</View>
```

Than, in e.g. `MainActivity`, you need get root layout and inflate dummy transparent view, and when marker selected (e.g. on click) you should get current screen coordinates of the selected `Marker` and place dummy transparent view exactly over it. For `RelativeLayout` it can be done via `setLeft()` for `x`-coordinate and `setTop()` for `y`-coordinate (of course you need adjust offsets according to the `Marker` anchors). Something like that:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String MAP_VIEW_BUNDLE_KEY = "MapViewBundleKey";
    static final LatLng KYIV = new LatLng(50.450311, 30.523730);

    private GoogleMap mGoogleMap;
    private RelativeLayout mMapViewRoot;
    private MapView mGoogleMapView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Bundle mapViewBundle = null;
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            mapViewBundle = savedInstanceState.getBundle(MAP_VIEW_BUNDLE_KEY);
        }

        mMapViewRoot = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.mapview_root);
        // dummy transparent view
        final View transparentView = View.inflate(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.transparent_view, mMapViewRoot);

        mGoogleMapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);
        mGoogleMapView.onCreate(mapViewBundle);
        mGoogleMapView.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
                mGoogleMap = googleMap;
                mGoogleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(KYIV).title("Kyiv"));
                mGoogleMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
                        // get screen coordinates of the marker
                        Projection projection = mGoogleMap.getProjection();
                        Point viewPosition = projection.toScreenLocation(marker.getPosition());

                        // place dummy transparent view over the marker
                        transparentView.setLeft(viewPosition.x);
                        transparentView.setTop(viewPosition.y);
                        return false;
                    }
                });

                mGoogleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(KYIV));

                ...

            }
        });

    }
...
```

Of course it's just example of idea and you should improve that code for markers sizes, anchors etc.